# ant-design-vue table missing sorting icon

Tags: css, vue.js, antd

[image]

i have a vue app with ant-design-vue table in it as a content. but the sorter icon is not showing up while i have import the icon correctly and working correctly when just display the icon. when i'm inspect the element, the icon is actually there but not displayed like in the picture above.

i have also tried by overwrite the css:

```
.ant-table-column-sorter-up .off .anticon .anticon-caret-up {
  font-size: 300px; //to see if there any change clearly
  color: pink
}
```

but there is nothing change on the template.

this is where i'm setting up the sorter on the ant design table:

```
{
    title: 'NAME',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name),
    sortDirections: ['ascend', 'descend'],
    scopedSlots: {
      customRender: 'name',
    },
    width: 250,
  },
```

[image]

it's shows there is no `<svg>` data in `<i>` like another ant-design icon. the `<i>` is empty. that means it's not affected by css. it's may affected by the ant-design-table.

and the function is working perfectly, just the icon is not showing up. is there anyway that i can do so that the sorter icon can showing up?

Comment: are you working in React, VueJS or something else?

Comment: i'm working with vue.js

Comment: would be useful to see what you wrote in your vuejs code rather than the inspector

Comment: unless that screenshot is it?